# Moved my login page, cant login now

Tags: identityserver4, angular-auth-oidc-client

I moved my login controls from account/login to the home page and removed the account controller and it's views. It all works fine on my machine (of course) but when I deploy to my test environment I get an error:

`No webpage was found for the web address: https://identity.blah.blah/account/login?returnUrl=%2Fconnect%2Fauthorize%2Fcallback%3Fclient_id%3Dclient.js%26redirect_uri%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fblah.blah%26respons etc`

My front end is Angular 6 and Im using angular-auth-oidc-client.

There's nothing in my code that creates this url.  The sts server url is just the root uri, no account/login.

`{
  "stsServer":"https://identity.blah.blah",
  "redirect_url":"http://app.blah.blah",
  "client_id":"app.client.js",
  "response_type":"id_token token",
  "scope":"openid profile api.v1",
  "post_logout_redirect_uri":"http://app.blah.blah",
  "start_checksession":true,
  "silent_renew":true,
  "startup_route":"/",
  "forbidden_route":"/forbidden",
  "unauthorized_route":"/unauthorized",
  "log_console_warning_active":true,
  "log_console_debug_active":false,
  "max_id_token_iat_offset_allowed_in_seconds":"10"
}`

Anyone got any ideas?  Maybe this is something hard coded somewhere I need to override?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it finally.  Not the best documentation... :/

```
var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(SetupIdentityServer)

private static void SetupIdentityServer(IdentityServerOptions 
  identityServerOptions)
{
  identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/";
  identityServerOptions.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Home/Logout";
}
```